# How can I get rid of these "\xb0" like strings

Tags: python, casting, ctypes

I've try to cast some data from memory using python and dll.

But there are some "unicode" things make me crazy to "cast" data using structs.

I've tried `decode('utf-8')` but I've Faced `UnicodeDecodeError`

I've changed some struct types, but nothing changed.

How can I Fix this problem?

```py
class NH0__OutBlock(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("hotime", c_char*6),
        ("hotime1", c_char*6),
        ("offerho1", c_char*6),
        ("bidho1", c_char*6),
        ("offerrem1", c_char*6),
        ("bidrem1", c_char*6),
        ("offercnt1", c_char*5),
        ("bidcnt1", c_char*5),
        ("offerho2", c_char*6),
        ("bidho2", c_char*6),
        ("offerrem2", c_char*6),
        ("bidrem2", c_char*6),
        ("offercnt2", c_char*5),
        ("bidcnt2", c_char*5),
        ("offerho3", c_char*6),
        ("bidho3", c_char*6),
        ("offerrem3", c_char*6),
        ("bidrem3", c_char*6),
        ("offercnt3", c_char*5),
        ("bidcnt3", c_char*5),
        ("offerho4", c_char*6),
        ("bidho4", c_char*6),
        ("offerrem4", c_char*6),
        ("bidrem4", c_char*6),
        ("offercnt4", c_char*5),
        ("bidcnt4", c_char*5),
        ("offerho5", c_char*6),
        ("bidho5", c_char*6),
        ("offerrem5", c_char*6),
        ("bidrem5", c_char*6),
        ("offercnt5", c_char*5),
        ("bidcnt5", c_char*5),
        ("totofferrem", c_char*6),
        ("totbidrem", c_char*6),
        ("totoffercnt", c_char*5),
        ("totbidcnt", c_char*5),
        ("futcode", c_char*8)
    ]
...
# RealMsgPacket.contents.pszData Type is ctypes.c_char_p
elif RealMsgPacket.contents.szTrCode.decode('euc-kr') == "NH0":
            Casted = cast(RealMsgPacket.contents.pszData, POINTER(c_char*int(RealMsgPacket.contents.nDataLength)))
            print(Casted.contents.value.strip())
...
```

```
b'035822 275822 028345\xb0028340\xb0000012 000019 00004 00016 028350\xb0028335\xb0000014 000025 00007 00022 028355\xb002
8330\xb0000007 000020 00004 00015 028360\xb0028325\xb0000007 000022 00005 00011 028365\xb0028320\xc0000010 000037 00010
00015 000050 000123 00030 00079 101PC000'
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The byte string at the end contains some 0xB0 bytes (probably some delimiter). This seems to be unrelated to Unicode. What is the expected output?

Comment: The Excpected Output is Those Chracters are well-splitted and fit into the structure. but It can't.

Comment: What do you mean "well-splitted"? What do you mean "fit into" the structure (the code that you show for casting the data doesn't seem to have anything to do with the first part of the class definition)? Why do you expect the data to look like anything meaningful at all? Just because the C language uses the name `char` for bytes, and the Python interface reflects that, doesn't mean that what you're looking at has *anything to do with* text at all.

Comment: Fixed it. They has an attribute on the header. Sorry for misinformation.